# Using ts-jest, getting `error TS2554: Expected 0 arguments, but got 1` for constructor

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

This is a weird one. I'm just getting back into TypeScript, and I'm trying to do some TDD. I got `ts-jest` setup and running my tests, but I've already run into a snag with something insanely simple and I can't figure it out.

organization.ts:

```
class Organization implements IOrganization {
    id: Id;
    name: string;

    constructor(name: string) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}


export default Organization;
```

test.ts:

```
import Organization from "./organization";
import Simulation from "./simulation";

it('stores the user organization', () => {
    let userOrganization = new Organization("does not matter");
}
```

VS Code isn't yelling at me, but when I try to run `ts-jest`, I get `error TS2554: Expected 0 arguments, but got 1` in my constructor. I must be missing something obvious.

Comment: I'm struggling to recreate this issue. I've created a [minimal example](https://github.com/YannickMeeus-StackOverflow-Answers/answer-55389386-tsjest-constructor-issue) based on what you've shown. If you could compare what you have against what I've tried to do, and come back to us with some more information we might be able to help you.

Comment: Hey, I really appreciate you making a whole project for this one. I spent some time looking it over, and after replacing my `tsconfig.json` with yours, it worked perfectly. No clue what was wrong with the one I had, but everything is in order now, thanks so much!

EDIT: D'oh. I was excluding `*test.ts* in my config per the TypeScript example, and that must have been messing with things. I removed that and my own config works as well, in case anyone comes across this with a similar issue.

Comment: Awesome, in that case could you add an answer to your own question with details on what fixed your problem? Comments are not guaranteed to stay around, but answers are :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was excluding `*test.ts* in my`tsconfig.json`per the TypeScript example, which I guess meant that`ts-jest` wasn't picking them up. After removing that exclusion, everything worked out. Shoutout to Yannick Meeus for helping me resolve that.